# Using .ssh keys in Crontab

Tags: ssh, cron, ssh-keys

One of my weekly scripts won't log into a `LAN` `server` now.  I added another entry into `~/.ssh/config` and the `crontab` entry isn't taking.  I just tried fixing it by specifically adding that `server` parameters (it was represented by a wildcard entry when the `crontab` was working)

```
Load key "/Users/rich/.ssh/id_rsa": Permission denied
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password)
```

How can I fix this so the cron has access to that box?  I tried copying over the key after my local change.

Here is my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
    Host *
        AddKeysToAgent yes
        UseKeychain yes

    Host uiop.local
        HostName uiop.local
        AddKeysToAgent yes
        UseKeychain yes
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        User rich

    Host qwer.local
        HostName qwer.local
        AddKeysToAgent yes
        UseKeychain yes
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        User rich

    Host github.com
        HostName github.com
        User Wonderful
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
        IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I also use `rsync` on a `LAN` box that isn't working now.  With one key is present, it's assumed that key is the only one to use.  But with the `config` file above, it still gets confused.  I'm questioning if the keys are added to the agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was permissions.  Set to `600` on the whole `.ssh` directory.